# What is the best way to recompile invalid objects in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I've inherited a group of Oracle instances and I've been deploying SQL scripts provided by a vendor that occasionally ends up moving various database objects into an invalid state. This in turn kicks off alerts from our alerting tool stating the same. I'm wanting to know what is the best approach to recompile these invalid objects post deployment. Is `COMPILE_SCHEMA` with `compile_all` set to FALSE the easiest, most reliable & efficient method to do this? I'm looking to introduce this step as a "cleanup" post deployment.

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/recompiling-invalid-schema-objects

Comment: Oracle recommends [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/spmsu/recompiling-all-invalid-objects.html#GUID-1023C5FB-B409-4F16-BCA1-C14CB9B7E625). But that doesn't really answer my question.